# Should we be notified if an answer to a question we asked has a higher score than the accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, notifications

I've been a member for nearly 9 years. I've asked 260 questions and counting. Some about old technology, some about new technology that became old. There's probably some questions of mine that have answers that score higher than the answer I accepted. Maybe at the time that was the best answer but now there's a new tool or somebody developed a better approach that wasn't available when the question was first asked and answered.

On the other side of things, I've sometimes found somebody else's question and attempted to use the accepted answer only to find that the higher voted, un-accepted answer turned out to be a better alternative.

I propose that there's either a notification linked to the question or a page on my profile where I can go to that would list questions I have asked with accepted answers that are not the highest scoring answer. Maybe I change my accepted answer, maybe not. That's up to the asker.

Considering the time aspect of this situation, it may not be that the original accepted answer is bad. Reducing their score because a better answer that may not have been available at the time may not be the best action to take. If possible, leaving the 2 points to the original answer might not be a bad idea.

Comment: There's a Feature Request somewhere to have the vote sort TRULY sort by votes, without pinning the accepted answer up top...  Not exactly what you want, but I think it's relevant. if I can find it somewhere

Comment: Just use a SEDE Query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/879547?UserId=160527

Comment: @BoltClock to be fair, you receive an inbox notification for every answer posted to your questions at the time they are posted.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Well I'm not sure why you're directing your comment at me and not the asker, but yes, that notification means you get a chance to evaluate the answer, and possibly pin it to the top immediately, without having to wait and see if it makes it there by vote.

Comment: @BoltClock _"each time you get the nagging feeling a new outstanding answer to one of your questions might have surfaced"_ each time a new outstanding answer to one of your questions surfaces, you get a notification in your inbox, or am I misunderstanding the intent of your comment?

Comment: @Tiny Giant: I'm having a go at rene's use of the word "just" that suggests that writing an SEDE query and manually pinging the database is the simple and obvious thing to do, let alone the right thing to do at all.

Comment: I got that, but the _"to be fair"_ part is that the query isn't something that would have to be done on a regular basis, but rather to remind yourself of _old_ outstanding answers that you had forgotten about. It would make no sense for _new_ outstanding answers as those _should_ still be fresh in your memory, (unless there is a memory issue). I understand that "Just write a query" can be like "Just fly to the moon" in some contexts, my comment(s) is (are) referring to the _"each time..."_ part. @BoltClock

Comment: While the SEDE Query is interesting and useful I don't think that should be the result of this. I'm not sure how many users actually know SEDE exists or would use it from time to time. If this were a feature in the site, I believe more users will re-evaluate better answers to old questions.

Comment: Rather than trying to convince the OP of a question to change their accepted answer when we're fairly confident that they haven't accepted the best answer, we could just do the *far* simpler option of not showing the answer the OP thinks as the best before answers that we're fairly sure are more useful than it.  Then you don't need to worry about 1) not being able to get a hold of the OP, who may not be reachable from the contact info SO has 2) them not caring anymore 3) them not knowing which answers are most useful 4) other.

Comment: Sorry for the bogus close - I read this too quickly. This is... An interesting idea; I'd never thought of approaching the problem that way, but I think there's some merit.

Comment: Hey look another legitimately useful feature request that will never get implemented.

Comment: I support this feature request. While we are at it, we should add some more reminders in exceptional circumstances. For example, if an answer reaches +10 score but the question does not have an accepted answer, then OP should get a reminder. Users should be encouraged to interact with the community.

Comment: Small correction: "leaving the 2 points to the original answer" - That's 15 points on their end, not 2.

Comment: @Servy - Your comment is exactly the answer I wanted to write. This is a UI problem - there may be a better answer, but it isn't displayed clearly enough. I'm against a notification to the OP, partly because I think many people will change the accepted answer just because the site asks them to - and that isn't a good reason.

Answer (score 8):

As per [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542):

> #### Which answer should I choose?
>
> […]
>
> The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.

As the person asking the question, it is completely up to you *personally* what answer you want to accept. And you should accept the answer that works best for you in that particular situation you were in.

*Votes* are a different thing and they are the primary thing that say how good or useful an answer is *in general*. As such, it is not necessarily required that the most upvoted answer is the one that is accepted. If that was the case, we wouldn’t have to ask the askers to actually accept answers; we could just pick the most upvoted answer automatically after a certain time.

So the accepted answer does not have to be the *best* answer, and you probably shouldn’t choose which answer to accept solely by the answer’s score.

As such, there is not really a good reason why you should be notified when a non-accepted answer passes an accepted answer in score. You are already notified *for every new* answer so **that** is when you should re-evaluate the answers to the question and may switch to a new, better one.

---

Of course, there are some exceptions, in particular edits to existing answers, which you’ll likely not realize unless you visit the question by pure chance and look at the answers again. But that really applies to all answers, not just new ones.

What I personally do is look through my questions (or answers) every once in a while when I receive a vote notification and cannot really remember the question that well. That gives me a chance to check everything again, maybe improve my posts and re-evaluate my votes or accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sounds like a good idea.

Even assuming your choice of accepted answer matched what most people would agree with at that time, there are multiple possible ways for things to change without you noticing:

- A problem is discovered / pointed-out in the accepted answer (which didn't affect your use of it so you didn't notice, or it was a conceptual Q&A not code).
- Another answer is edited to become a lot better.  (You don't get notifications about answer edits, only when they're first posted.  When I make a big edit within a few days of posting an answer, I often @ping the OP to let them know.)
- Best-practices or the language or technology itself changes, deprecating something in the accepted answer or whatever.

Any of these factors could lead to voting that favours an answer that didn't look so good at the time you accepted an answer, without a notification popping up to prompt you to go re-evaluate.

---

I like your suggestion of something built-in to your profile page to show you which of your questions have higher-rated non-accepted answers.  (Something like @rene's SEDE query, I guess.)

Sending a notification once ever per question is maybe good.  As far as heuristics and thresholds, we probably don't want to spam people because of voting fluctuations on recently-asked questions.  So maybe ping when a non-accepted answer has been at least 1 vote higher for 2 days?

Maybe one ping ever *per answer*, rather than per question?  You wouldn't want an early competitor to the accepted answer to hide the signal from a months-later edit that creates a very good answer.

---

Commenters on the question point out a potential problem: some users might change their accept just because "the site asks them to".  So be careful with the wording to avoid implying that you *should* change your accept vote.  Just provide it as a way to see questions where you *might* want to.